# NetLogo scheduling of different actions

Tags: timer, netlogo, scheduling

I am very new to NetLogo and now I try to understand the logic behind NetLogo. I am building my first model and can not figure out how the procedures have to be ordered to do what I would like them to.
What my model should do:

- In the “morning” (beginning of the simulation) spread out my agents randomly
- Then let them move “uphill” with a little bit of randomness to go to the places with the highest insolation in their surroundings.
- Stay there for a number of ticks (between 25 and 34)
- After my timer has expired they should start foraging – so far just moving around randomly – the timer should not start again and also the “uphill” behaviour should not be executed again

What the model does:

- The agents spread randomly
- They move to the place with the highest insolation in their surrounding (uphill)
- The timer starts and counts down
- The agents start moving again– but the I am trapped in the uphill – stay put till the timer expires “loop” again

I guess that it is a real beginner-mistake… Could you please explain to me how to get this right?

```
to go
  move-turtles
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles
  [ifelse insolation <= max [insolation] of neighbors
  [continue]
  [bask]
  pen-down
  ]
end

to continue   ;; a turtle procedure
  ifelse random-float 1.0 < 0.7
  [uphill insolation]
  [move-to one-of neighbors]
end

to bask  ;; a turtle procedure
  set count-down count-down - 1
  set label count-down
  if count-down = 0
  [
   forage
   set label ""
  ]
end


to forage  ;; turtle procedure 
  set heading (random-normal 180 30)
  fd random-normal 3 2
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the countdown value initially?

Comment: Hi JenB, here is the section where I set the count down (in the set-up turtle procedure): to set-up turtles create-lizards 25 [
    set size 7
    set color green
    set shape "lizard"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask turtles
  [set count-down random 10 + 25]
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you only want them to do the uphill / bask once per day but they do it repeatedly. Imagine a turtle has done their basking, the forage procedure sends them in a random direction once. Now, the next tick, they are faced with:

```
ifelse insolation <= max [insolation] of neighbors
[ continue ]
[ bask ]
```

So they look around and compare the insolation values and then select the 'continue' or 'bask' procedure depending on the comparison. If they get the continue procedure, they move to one of the neighbouring patches, either to the one with the largest insolation value or randomly. If they get the bask procedure, nothing happens except that the label gets turned on. This is because the value of count-down is 0 from the last time they basked, so it is -1 by the time the code checks whether the value is 0.

Once nothing happens, they are faced with the same choice next tick and will have the same outcome. So once the turtle is at the insolation peak, it will stay there indefinitely.

If you want something to only occur once, the easiest thing to do is to add a variable that remembers whether it has happened yet. NetLogo convention has true/false (yes/no) variables with a question mark at the end. So you can do something like (assuming you have added 'bask-over?' to the `turtles-own` and initialised it as false):

```
to bask  ;; a turtle procedure
  set count-down count-down - 1
  set label count-down
  if count-down = 0
  [ forage
    set label ""
    set bask-over? true
  ]
end
```

And you then bring that variable into the test for whether to continue or bask:

```
to move-turtles
  ask turtles
  [ ifelse bask-over? or insolation <= max [insolation] of neighbors
    [ continue ]
    [ bask ]
    pen-down
  ]
end
```

Note that `if bask-over?` is the same as `if bask-over? = true`. Similarly you can use `if not bask-over?` instead of `if bask-over? = false`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem became a little bit smaller but is not solved so far. I tried to modify your code so that if both - basking and continue - are over, just the forage bahaviour is executed. I was not able to do this... When running your code the turtles move again after basking, basking does not occure any more but continue does. So the turtles stop basking, do forage for one tick and they do the continue again. I want them to do the continue once, bask once and then just do the forage... Seems to be tricky :)

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it: to move-turtles
  ask turtles [ 
  (ifelse insolation <= max [insolation] of neighbors
  [continue]
  [bask])
  if continue-over? and bask-over?
  [forage]
  pen-down
  ]
end  - could this be correct?